# JWT-Auth responds token_not_provided when i try to validate the token

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, jwt

As far as i know everything is proper in back end that is Laravel, because its working well in Postman, but when i try to validate token from front-end (Angular 4) JWT-Auth throws error `{"error":"token_not_provided"}`
This is how my request header looks like.

```
POST /api/user HTTP/1.1
Accept:          application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-IN,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  439
Content-Type:    application/json
Host:            localhost:8000
Origin:          http://localhost:4200
Referer:         http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36

{
    "header": {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV .... vBMbwBypj6uv4Ks",
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
}
```

Comment: can u pls post the code where u decode the token eg: `this.jwtHelper.decodeToken()`

Comment: why should I decode it before validating? I validate user in server side

Comment: But the error is in client side, right ?

Comment: Very first thing i want to know is whether my HTTP Request header is proper or not? If yes why does JWT-Auth cannot fetch token from this